# Swift Reference Variable from Specific Instance of Different Class

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiviewcontroller

I'm new to Swift and iOS in general.  I'm using Swift to write an app.  This app has two files, `ViewController.swift` and `BTService.swift`.

`ViewController.swift` has a class `ViewController` of type `UIViewController`, and `BTService.swift` has a class `BTService` of types `NSObject` and  `CBPeripheralDelegate`.  I have a slider set up in the `UIViewController` class, and its value is assigned to variable `currentValue`.

Now, I want to be able to reference `currentValue` from within the `BTService` class.  How can I go about doing this?  I've noticed that if I define a variable, `test`, in the file `ViewController` *before* the class `UIViewController`, that I *can* reference `test` in `BTService`.  But that's of no use to me since I can't (to my knowledge) get the slider value to be assigned to test unless test is defined within the `UIViewController` class.

Here's my ViewController and the currentValue variable definition.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet var positionLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var positionSlider: UISlider!
@IBOutlet var connectionLabel: UILabel!

@IBAction func sliderValChanged(sender: UISlider) {

    var currentValue = Float(positionSlider.value)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`NSUserDefaults`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/index.html) to store data within your application and share it between view controllers.

In the example you give, you could store it like this:

```
let defaults: NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
defaults.setFloat(Float(positionSlider.value), forKey: "sliderValue") // Write to NSUserDefaults
defaults.synchronize()
```

Then, whenever you need access to it in another file (or in this one), you can just call `floatForKey`:

```
if let currentValue: Float = defaults.floatForKey("sliderValue") {
    // Access slider value
} else {
    // Probably not saved
}
```

Comment: If i put the line `let currentValue: Float = defaults.floatForKey("sliderValue")` in the BTService class, it doesn't recognize the name "defaults".  I defined defaults in the ViewController class.  is this what i'm supposed to do?

Comment: @RossM. If you want to access it from the `BTService` class, you have to define `defaults` again (just copy and paste the first line) in that class before you try to access it using `floatForKey`.

Comment: okay that works!  problem is that it only shows the initial value for the slider, but doesn't update the variable with the new value if you change it.  the only way i could think of how to get it to update would be to reference sliderPosition but that produces the same problem that the NSUserDefaults method fixed.  is there something really simple i'm missing?

Comment: @RossM. Get rid of all references to the value of the slider and use `NSUserDefaults` in its place. Put that first code block inside of `sliderValChanged` so that it updates whenever the slider changes.

Comment: "Values returned from NSUserDefaults are immutable, even if you set a mutable object as the value. For example, if you set a mutable string as the value for "MyStringDefault", the string you later retrieve using stringForKey: will be immutable."--from the swift documentation. Am I misunderstanding this, or does it basically say that my NSUserDefaults can't change?

Comment: @RossM. No; it's saying that *NSUserDefaults does not store mutable **data types***. So, for example, if you try to store an `NSMutableArray`, it will automatically be cast as an `NSArray` and will be that type when you pull it anywhere else. However, you can cast that result as an `NSMutableArray` after fetching it. If you use native Swift types only (`String`, `Int`, etc.), you shouldn't run into any issues in that regard.

Comment: `@IBAction func sliderValChanged(sender: UISlider) {
        
        let defaults: NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        
        defaults.synchronize()
        let currentValue: Float = defaults.floatForKey("sliderVaue")
        println(currentValue)` I put this in the BTService class, but I'm not getting any results in the console. I should be, though, right?

Comment: Note that I'm not getting any syntax errors with this code; it's just not doing what I'm expecting.

Comment: @RossM. You don't need to synchronize defaults before reading from them (only after writing to them – and that's only with iOS 7 and earlier). It looks like you have a typo in your key: `sliderVaue` -> `sliderValue`.

Comment: My `sliderValChanged` function now looks like `let defaults: NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        let currentValue: Float = defaults.floatForKey("sliderValue")
        println(currentValue)`  Still no syntax errors, but it's also still not printing anything to the console.  Any other ideas as to why this isn't working as expected?  By the way, thanks a ton for your persistence in helping out a newbie.  I really do appreciate it :)

Comment: It's no problem. Are you sure you've set a value for `sliderValue` in your other VC?

Comment: `@IBAction func sliderValChanged(sender: UISlider) {
        
        let defaults: NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        defaults.setFloat(Float(positionSlider.value), forKey: "sliderValue") // Write to NSUserDefaults
        defaults.synchronize()
        let currentValue: Float = defaults.floatForKey("sliderValue")
        var currentValueString=NSString(format: "%.5f", currentValue)
        positionLabel.text=currentValueString
        println(currentValue)

    }`
Here's my sliderValChanged function in my VC.

Comment: @RossM. I don't know what could be wrong, then (as long as you actually change the slider value before trying to access its data). You might want to ask another question to see if someone else can help you (you can link back to this one if it helps provide context).

Answer (score 0):

Is your `BTService` a property within the UIViewController?

Could you use Key Value Observing (KVO)

Inside your UIViewController

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    self.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "positionSlider.value", options: .New, context: nil)
}

deinit() {
    self.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "positionSlider.value")
}

override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String, ofObject object: AnyObject, change: [NSObject : AnyObject], context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
    if keyPath == "positionSlider.value" {
        // update service property
    }
}
```

Comment: it's not a property actually, it's a separate class.