# NSUserDefaults Seemingly not Creating Globally Accessible Variables

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, uiviewcontroller

I'm new to Swift and iOS in general, and would appreciate any help on this...I'm making an app with one file called `ViewController.swift`, which contains the `ViewController` class, and another file called `BTService.swift`, which contains the `BTService` class.  I have a slider set up in the VC, and I want to take its value and use it in the `BTService` class.  I asked a question about this previously ([Swift Reference Variable from Specific Instance of Different Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29045167/swift-reference-variable-from-specific-instance-of-different-class)) and someone suggested I use `NSUserDefaults` to accomplish this.  This is my VC class with the slider value, `positionSlider.value` assigned to a key `sliderValue`

`class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var positionLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var positionSlider: UISlider!
    @IBOutlet var connectionLabel: UILabel!
    @IBAction func sliderValChanged(sender: UISlider) {`

```
    let defaults: NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    println(positionSlider.value)
    defaults.setFloat(Float(positionSlider.value), forKey: "sliderValue") // Write to NSUserDefaults
    defaults.synchronize()
    let currentValue: Float = defaults.floatForKey("sliderValue")
    var currentValueString=NSString(format: "%.5f", currentValue)
```

`sliderValue` is stored as a `float` in `NSUserDefaults`.  Now, from my understanding, I can then go to my `BTService` class and simply do this:

`@IBAction func sliderValChanged(sender: UISlider) {
        let defaults: NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        let currentValue: Float = defaults.floatForKey("sliderValue")
        println(currentValue)

    }`

However, this isn't working.  I don't get any syntax errors, but I also don't see any value printed to the console when I tweak the slider.  Interesting note is that I *do* see an output of the value when I put a `println` statement in the VC, which shows that currentValue is being defined and is functioning like it should.  Any help on this would be very much appreciated.  Thanks so much!

Comment: have you check positionSlider.value conforms to float?

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure that's it's default type.

Comment: positionSlider.value already returns a Float. No need to force to synchronize

Comment: You should read the value from the slider not from the userDefaults

Comment: If you would like to store the slider value when it changes you need to update userDefaults value for the key "sliderValue" with the slider value in this case sender.value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@IBAction func sliderValChanged(sender: UISlider) {
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setFloat(sender.value, forKey: "sliderValue")
    let currentValue = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().floatForKey("sliderValue")
    println(currentValue)

}
```